# Loading JavaScript files asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, dynamic-loading

I need to get some scripts from the different social networking site and cache them.  I want the function to be asynchronous, and non-blocking.

I have settled with a script, but I am not really sure if it is not overly complicated to do the job.

I did replace a normal `for` loop, and this method is much faster. I do not know why, but it just is.

```
// Cached scritps
var cachedScriptPromises = {};

// Location of the scripts
var Scripts : {
    twitter    : '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js',
    facebook   : 'http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share',
    googleplus : 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js',
    linkedin   : 'http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js'
};

// When the button is clicked all the scripts
// are loaded. The conainers are already
// on the website. They will be filled
// as soon as the script is loaded.
jQuery('a.share-link').click(function(){
    for( var script in Scripts ){
        jQuery.cachedGetScript( Scripts[script] );
    }
});


// Function that get and caches the scripts
jQuery.cachedGetScript = function( script ) {
    if ( !cachedScriptPromises[ script ] ) {
        cachedScriptPromises[ script ] = jQuery.Deferred(function( defer ) {
            jQuery.getScript( script ).then( defer.resolve, defer.reject );
        }).promise();
    }
    return cachedScriptPromises[ script ];
};
```

Eventually this function can be expanded by adding some before and after actions. The thing is that the files are loaded so quickly that I have removed these features, but I am planning to do this as soon as the project becomes bigger.

Does anyone have any suggestions on making this better?  Maybe some adjustments to the code, or go a complete other way with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you don't need to use jquery deferred objects for this task. Just use script tags with sources - they will be downloaded in parallel from CDNs (try to use CDN, its always a good idea). The amount of parallel requests will be limited by browser restrictions.

Since your code just replaces default browser technique, for more sophisticated features (like dependent components, libraries that you really want to defer, because they are not used until some action on the page), use

- http://jsload.net/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/get/
- deferred objects as you did

Comment: I do not understand why using another library would be better. I am trying to minimize the amount of libraries I load on init. I already use jQuery, I think that is more than enough. I am not going to load another YUI or jsload library. As for the CDN, the files are already on CDN's, they files are not downloaded from my server, or am I missing something here. Can you point out some benefits of using another library ?

Comment: Just as I said, I did not see in the code anything with regards to dependencies of one library on another. If you need it, you will create the whole jsload-like infrastructure yourself. If you don't, you don't need script to load scripts, just load them through <script> tags..

Comment: Ah after a long search and read I finally understand where you are driving at. It is about non-blocking loading of external files. It could also be done with just native javascript, without any library at all. I will read a little more about this, it looks like a good option. Thank for the suggestion.

Comment: Glad I could help and sorry I couldn't get back to you with more explanations.

Comment: Nice read for async script loading https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/